# Intel WiDi needs Intel adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, display, streaming

I have the processor requirement and, subsequently, the graphics card. Why do I need to have a specific wireless card?

The question is: **Can I bypass somehow this "requirement"** without using extra hardware?

I'm using windows 7 and the target device (tv) supports both WiDi and Miracast.

Answer (score 1):

WiDi does support some non-Intel adapters, mostly BCM43xx, but if your adapter is not [in the list](http://supportkb.intel.com/wireless/wireless-display/templates/selfservice/intelwidi/#portal/1026/article/2511), there is no way around it.

Miracast is a little different. There is no Miracast support on Windows 7 so its Intel WiDi(v3.5+) again. However Windows 8.1 has Miracast support builtin so its possible to get Miracast working without WiDi. The display adapter has to support WDDM 1.3(HD4000 and above) and the WiFi driver needs to support NDIS 6.4. You may want to do some research to see if there is a NDIS 6.4 driver available for your wifi adapter.